# Prepend then redirect

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I want to redirect `stderr` to a file for logging purposes:

```
2>> "$logFile"
```

How can I prepend the string `"error: "` to every line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a process substitution.

```
2> >(awk '{print "error: " $0}' >> "$logfile")
```

Or with old shells with broken process substitution support:

```
{ { prog >&3; } 2>&1 | sed 's/^/error: /' >> "$logfile"; } 3>&1
```

Here we save `prog`'s stdout to fd 3, pipe its stderr to sed and at the end restore fd 3 back to stdout.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the `awk` using only bash builtins?

Comment: I would like to use exec <redirection> to do the whole thing, so that it is in effect during all my script. If I execute `exec >&3` I get the error "3: Bad file descriptor"

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `sed`:

```
2> >(sed -u 's/^/error: /' >> "$logfile")
```

Using just bash builtins might not be possible because this mechanism of prefixing a string needs to work with a stream.

Note use of `gnu sed` option `-u` (`--unbuffered`) to load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often.

[Code Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/BkKx_r5EL)

Comment: Between sed and awk which would be more efficient?

Comment: Probably both will perform on similar lines but my guess is that it will still be more efficient than using  a `while` loop

Comment: It does work in my testing by prefixing each line with `"error: "` in `$logfile`

Comment: Maybe relevant: on AIX bash uses temporary files in the /tmp directory and not /def/fd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208829/discussion-between-roland-and-anubhava).

Comment: Seems to be a bug with named pipes
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-11/msg00104.html

Answer (score 1):

A pure-Bash version:

```
2> >(while read -r line ; do echo "error: $line" ; done >> "$logFile")
```

. . . but note that this will misbehave if the program writes any null bytes, or if the program doesn't write a newline after the last line. (Both of those issues are solvable, but at some point we have to question whether it's worth it just to avoid calling awk or sed.)

Answer (score 1):

Since process substitution is buggy on my AIX with Bash 4.2.50 the alternative from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution is to use a FIFO:

```
logFile='/tmp/stderr.log'
fifoFile='/tmp/log123.fifo'
mkfifo $fifoFile
glub 2>> $fifoFile & #the & is needed because otherwise the FIFO will block
cat $fifoFile | sed -u 's/^/error: /' >> "$logFile"
```

[Code demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SJgVJc9NL)

The ampersand `&` at the third line is needed because otherwise the FIFO will block until there is a reader.

Another option is to just not prepend anything during execution, wait until the logging is finished and process the log file afterwards.

Comment: Is a fifo really required? I think `{ { glub >&3; } 2>&1 | sed 's/^/error: /' >> "$logfile"; } 3>&1` should also work fine

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks, looks good to me! Why don't you post this as answer? How about adding some explanation also? I'm not sure I understand the reason for all the braces and what exactly is going on with the redirections, especially to fd 3.

Comment: @oguzismail also how could you rewrite your redirections using exec so that they are valid during the whole script?

Comment: updated my answer with that and a brief explanation. Wrt *how could you rewrite your redirections using exec*, I didn't understand this part